# Define metric to use after ab test is finished

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, ab-test

Let's consider such a setup for an experiment: I've made some new feature to the existing system and want to test, whether this feature will bring positive value to the system. May be I don't know what exactly should this new feature improve (revenue, amount of purchases, ctr, churn rate, ...). So what problems I might face (in statistical sence), if I just start A/B test without clear metric, that I want to look at and instead just wait till the end of experiment (yes, I know you should define sample size, based on mde, which is defined with the metric in mind, but let's assume that I'll just run experiment for a reasonable amount of time - say 2 weeks, and my website is huge (meaning that I'll definitely have required amount of observations for that 2 week period)) and after experiment is done - I'll define whether I'd like to roll out this feature for the whole system, looking at different metrics and noticing, whether at least one of them is statsig positive?

So, saying shortly: are there any cons for not determining main metric(s) in a/b test, but rather just analysing all the metrics at the end of experiment and making decision (to roll out the feature or not) and "cherry-picking" those, that are statsig positive. Here we only talk about the situation, where none of the metrics is statsig negative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are problems and they go beyond statistical significance. When you cherry pick your metric, your effect size estimates will be biased, not just your p values. How biased it will be depends on the number of metrics and probably on other characteristics, but here's a simple example with four metrics that have no relationship:

set.seed(1234)

condition <- c(rep("A", 1000), rep("B", 1000))
y1 <- rnorm(2000)
y2 <- rnorm(2000)
y3 <- rnorm(2000)
y4 <- rnorm(2000)

```
m1 <- lm(y1~condition)
m1$coefficients #0.04

m2 <- lm(y2~condition)
m2$coefficients #-0.04

m3 <- lm(y3~condition)
m3$coefficients #0.08

m4 <- lm(y4~condition)
m4$coefficients #-0.05
```

So, you would cherry pick and report just 0.08. That's misleading.

You could divide your data into train and test, then find the biggest effect in the train set and then estimate it in the test set.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is essentially shooting the side of a barn and then later drawing targets around your bullet holes so as to make it appear that you are a good marksman.

Setting aside the fact that this is poor scientific practice, you have other problems:

- Assuming the change does *nothing* to any of the metrics, then the probability you make at least one erroneous detection increases with the number of metrics you check.  An erroneous detection means you will be expecting changes to your metric, and none will be seen.  Your product side colleagues will likely demand answers why nothing has changed, and you won't have much in the way of an explanation.
- Your justification for sample size (i.e. 2 weeks run time and "I'll definitely have required amount of observations") begs the question "required amount of data for what"?
- Because your justification for sample size is poor, you risk running an underpowered experiment. If you *do* detect a difference, and a difference exists, then you will very likely over estimate the effect and hence be disappointed with the change upon rollout to the entire user base.

While I don't mind a fishing expedition, you need to follow up your experiment with *another* -- independent and well designed -- experiment to validate the results you found.